# Parse pricing structure

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I realise that this isn't a coding question but I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this.

I'm building an app that lists users (300 at a time) and displays thumbnail images and I anticipate having thousands of users using the app.

As far as I can tell getting the 300 users is seen as 1 request in Parse but each thumbnail file would be 1 request per thumbnail. Is that right?

So if you get 30 requests per second for free before having to upgrade, then it would only take 6 users to use up over 1800 requests in 1 minute.

Or does the collectionView only download the thumbnail when it scrolls into view?

Am I correct in my assumption?
Is there anyway to retrieve all users along with the thumbnail file as one request?

Comment: I don't know about pricing but the collection view loading behavior is up to your code in terms of whether you pre-load images or only generate a request when needed.

Comment: At the moment I have put the code to fetch the thumbnail file in cellForItemAtIndexPath. Is the behaviour of this that the thumbnail file only downloads when the cell comes into view? (I don't currently have enough data to test this out yet).

Comment: Table views only ask you to update cells as they become visible unless you call an explicit update method.  Even then it's only going to affect visible ones.  You can also look at a cache so that you don't re-request things that are already available on the device.

Comment: That's good to know but I guess the issue remains that 6 users can still easily scroll through all 300 thumbnails within 1 minute. As you suggest caching may be a way round this but is there a way to fetch all thumbnail files in one request?

Comment: You can create `PFFile` columns so that each record can have files stored with them. Then the file gets fetched at the same time as the record.

Comment: That's what I have, but you have to call getDataInBackground. I was assuming that was another api request, does that mean it's a data transfer instead?